# How to make the icon rotated based on the prop?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How to rotate the icon based on the activeColor prop?
I need the icon to be rotated when the activeColor prop is active.
So far I managed to write sth like that, but it is not working:(
Can you please help and advise on this?

```
export const Icon = styled.div`
  ${({ activeColor }) =>
    activeColor &&
    css`
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    `}
`
```

Any help would be apppreciated.

Regards,
Emilia

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, write a css property and change the value based on  prop.

```
export const Icon = styled.div`
    transform: {(props) => (props.activeColor ? "rotate(180deg)" : 
               "rotate(0deg)")};
`;
```